# how to save ui state of an activity

Tags: android, state, lifecycle, android-activity

i am stuck with this problem. let me explain the problem.

I have two activities for simplicity sake, let us name the first activity as **parent** activity and the second activity as **child** activity.

In parent activity i have a listview of some items and below listview i have a price filter button to filter the list based on price. When user click the price filter button then child activity starts.

In child activity i am providing a seekbar to set the price. In child activty i have two buttons below the seekbar cancel and filter.

Now i have three different scenario:

1. In first scenario **:** user click the price filter button in parent activity than child activity starts.In child activity user adjust the seekbar ( **LET say this state of child activity as STATE1**) and than clicks the **filter** button then user will go in parent activity and will see the filter result now if user again click 
   the price filter button than child actvity should start where user left means it should show the **STATE1**..(i am able to do this scenario by setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT in both activities)
2. In second scenario **:** user first going with first scenario and now click the price filter button in parent activity then child activity starts.In child activity user adjust the seekbar ( **LET say this state of child activity as STATE2**) but now user do not want to filter the list so clicks the **cancel** button then user simply will come back to the parent activity now if user again click the price filter button than child actvity should show the **STATE1**. but it is showing **STATE2**
3. In third scenario **:** user first going with first scenario and now click the price filter button in parent activity then child activity starts.In child activity user adjust the seekbar ( **LET say this state of child activity as STATE3**) but now user do not want to filter the list so clicks the **android phones back** button then user simply will come back to the parent activity now if user again click the price filter button than child actvity should show the **STATE1** but here child activity is showing neither **STATE1** nor **STATE2** as it is recreating.

In short only in first scenario i want to save the state of child activity and want to show this state in every scenario.(I tried my best to get you understand my problem)

i want to clear that i need to save the seekbar state. seekbar values i will carry by some way.

To do this task i have read the activity lifecycle five times but by this way i am able to store only some desired values, i am not able to store the seekbar state.

Guys nothing is helping so please please help me.

Thanks in advance

Ranjan

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just get the value of the seekbar using `Seekbar.getProgress()`?

Comment: thanx for reply, but actually i am using double thumb seekbar which i got from http://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/  and second thing i want the adjusted seekbar state, values i will carry by some way. so please tel me some other way

Comment: Looking at the code for `range-seek-bar` there are two methods you want to use `RangeSeekBar.getSelectedMinValue()` and `RangeSeekBar.getSelectedMaxValue()`

Comment: i have seen these methods, i can get the values from these methods but my question is to set the seek bar position at previous state. May be i am getting you wrong so please can u elaborate how to do this task.

Comment: @ranjan, are you serious? How is it you are using a object without even reading its source? Along with the `getSelectedMaxValue()` and `getSelectedMinValue()` are two setter methods `setSelectedMaxValue()` and `setSelectedMinValue()`  I imagine they could be helpful